# How to pass map<string,string> as parameter in javascript

Tags: apex, javascript, map, onclick

I have a method :

```
webservice static String myMethod(String objectType, String recordId, Map<String,String> fieldValueMap )
```

I need to pass this in onclick javascript custom button.

```
sforce.apex.execute("myClass","myMethod",{objectType:"payId",recordId:"recId",...});
```

But I am not finding a way to pass a way to pass map as a parameter. Can anyone help on above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a map like this:

```
Map<String, String> MyMap = new map<String, String> {
    'key1' => 'value1', 
    'key2' => 'value2'};
```

Then you must send an object containing a Property for each Map. Each Property will be named as the Key for the Map, and and the value of that Property will be the Value for the Map. The JavaScript object to send would look like:

```
var someObject = {};   
someObject['key1'] = 'value1';
someObject['key2'] = 'value2';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create wrapper/separate class class as

```
webservice static String myMethod(Parameters  parameter )


public class Parameters   {
public String objectType{get;set;}
public String recordId{get;set;}
public Map<String,String> fieldValueMap {get;set;}
}


sforce.apex.execute("myClass","myMethod",parameter 
 : {objectType:"payId",recordId:"recId",...});
```

Comment: no my question is how to pass Map<String,String> as parameter in key value format

Comment: you can pass e.g. fieldValueMap : {"FirstName":"Prakash", "LastName":"Nawale"}